# PHP version matters or not?

Tags: php, core

I've been running certain 5.6 for a long while and wondering if I ever should migrate to 7.0 or just leave alone. Installation instructions say 7.0 is recommended but so is 5.6

Anyone have opinions on this?

---Update:  I have upgraded my WordPress site to 7.2 without too much trouble.  However the Drupal 7 / Civi site when I tried to update, I got 503 errors and had to roll back.  I think there are some really tight controls the consulting firm put into place.  I kept reading about FastCGI and NGINX and had no idea.  I do not know about these and if they are used.  I know that FPM is used.  I want to update before year end but I am scared.  Anyone?

Comment: Thank youb to the first answer. It was very good. Read articles

Answer (score 2):

A few considerations:

1) You want to be running a version that has security support. See https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php  Both 5.6 & 7.0 have support to Dec 2018.  Beyond that, you need 7.1+ (although 7.1 is not currently recommended for use with CiviCRM - https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/)

2) php 7 is faster than 5.6.  See http://www.zend.com/en/resources/php7_infographic  Why not run the faster version?

3) Maintaining support for old versions of php is a drain on development resources and prevents CiviCRM taking advantage of new php features.

So, yes upgrade to 7.0 now (providing you are on the current 4.7.* release) and expect to keep upgrading.

[Edit: prompted by Graham's comment.]

Php requirements links:

- [Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/drupal-7-php-requirements#php_required)
- [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/drupal-8-php-requirements)
- [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)
- [Joomla!](https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements)
- [Backdrop](https://backdropcms.org/requirements)

Comment: Would he useful to understand, in this context, what the level of support is for PHP 7 among the host CMS systems. Anyone got that detail handy?

Comment: I am running 4.7.29 and keep that updated.  But upon trying to upgrade , I ran into a problems.  I am running Drupal 7 and do not know it very well.  I tried to update to just 7.0 but I think I may have done it wrong and left some modules out.

Comment: Check you have the php7 version of these modules: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php-extensions